# Setting IFS with read not behaving as expected

Tags: bash, read

Wondering if any of the good folks here can explain what is happening. The values seem to be being parsed out of the input string, but all stored in the first variable.

```
bash-4.2# SYNC_REPO='vendor:path'
bash-4.2# echo $SYNC_REPO
vendor:path
bash-4.2# IFS=':' read REPO_PROVIDER REPO_DIR REST <<< ${SYNC_REPO}
bash-4.2# echo "[$REPO_PROVIDER, $REPO_DIR, $REST]"
[vendor path, , ]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Repro on 4.2 (using the `ubuntu:12.04` Docker image), no repro on 4.3 or newer. Probably a bug that was fixed, but I couldn't spot anything relevant in [the `CHANGES`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES)

Comment: Have you tried quoting <<< ${SYNC_REPO} like this `<<< "${SYNC_REPO}"`

Comment: Bash 4.2 bug. For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20163550

Comment: Thank you - muru and user234931. Thought I was going nuts. So many hours wasted :(

Comment: As per comments from muru and user234931 it turns out this is a bug in bash 4.2